# What is the difference between the DisabledByDefault and Enabled SSL/TLS registry keys on Microsoft Windows?

Tags: windows, ssl, schannel

Microsoft provides best practices guidance for Transport Layer Security (TLS). This document describes registry keys that can enable or disable a specific protocol.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/tls#configuring-schannel-protocols-in-the-windows-registry

For example, to enable TLS 1.2, you can add the following registry keys.

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Client]
"DisabledByDefault"=dword:00000000
"Enabled"=dword:FFFFFFFF

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Server]
"DisabledByDefault"=dword:00000000
"Enabled"=dword:FFFFFFFF
```

What is the difference between `DisabledByDefault` and `Enabled`? They seem redundant.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the [`SCHANNEL_CRED` structure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/Schannel/ns-schannel-_schannel_cred) that is [passed to `AcquireCredentialsHandle` as part of setting up a secure channel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/secauthn/obtaining-schannel-credentials), you can optionally manually select the protocols to support, in the `grbitEnabledProtocols` bitmask field.

Thus, **`Enabled` governs what protocols you can enable here while `DisabledByDefault` specifies whether the protocol is enabled if you omit this field** (i.e. leave it as `0`).

- The [Managing SSL/TLS Protocols and Cipher Suites for AD FS | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/operations/manage-ssl-protocols-in-ad-fs) article recommends to set `DisabledByDefault` to `1` for disabled protocols, too, in addition to setting `Enabled` to `0`. So **it looks like `DisabledByDefault` is used unconditionally to autogenerate the value for this field if it's omitted.**

The field's note says that it's not recommended for use in new code. So these two registry values are *almost* redundant:

> For new development, applications should set `grbitEnabledProtocols` to
>   zero and use the protocol versions enabled on the system by default.
>
> This member is used only by the Microsoft Unified Security Protocol
>   Provider security package.
>
> The global system registry settings take precedence over this value.
>   For example, if SSL3 is disabled in the registry, it cannot be enabled
>   using this member.

It's unclear what happens if you try to use a non-enabled protocol. Judging by the last paragraph and [a lack of any relevant `AcquireCredentialsHandle` error code for this case](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa374716(v=vs.85).aspx), my guess is it's probably ignored.

Answer (score 16):

## DisabledByDefault and Enabled are not redundant

When `DisabledByDefault` flag is set to 1, SSL / TLS version X is not used by default. If an SSPI app requests to use this version of SSL / TLS, it will be negotiated. In a nutshell, SSL is not disabled when you use `DisabledByDefault` flag.

When `Enabled` flag is set to 0, SSL / TLS version X is disabled and cannot be nagotiated by any SSPI app (even if `DisabledByDefault` flag is set to 0).

For more information, [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/security/tls/tls-registry-settings) describes what SSL version is maintained or not, and how to disable it.

Comment: Ok, but if DisabledByDefault = 0 for a protocol, then would there ever be a need to set Enabled = 1?